# What do I need in the package.json of my npm package, to install it to another project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I'm trying to make a small-ish react component that can be used in other projects. This is what I have in my package.json so far:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./dist/lib.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/lib.module.js",
  "source": "src/components/MyPackage/index.js",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/lib.js",
    "./styles.css": "./dist/lib.css"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "microbundle": "^0.15.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "microbundle --jsx React.createElement --jsxFragment React.Fragment --jsxImportSource react",
    "watch": "microbundle watch --jsx React.createElement --jsxFragment React.Fragment --jsxImportSource react"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

The `exports` fields, `module` and `source` are for microbundle to know what and where to bundle.

This repo is in a private bitbucket repository, and I've installed it like this:
`npm i git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:myuser/mypackage.git`, but it doesn't let me import the package. When looking in my `node_modules/mypackage`, I only see the package.json, and the README, but no js files.

The weird thing is this package works when I import it locally using `npm link`.

Comment: When you import your module node will try to load whatever file you declared as your `main:`. In this case node will try to load `node_modules/my-package/dist/lib.umd.js`. Make sure that file is committed and exist in your git repo or wherever you want install your module from. Node will not try to run your build process for you, it will just try to load the file

Comment: Yup you're right, the dist folder was ignored by git, so no way to get it when installing from the git source, except for building it post-install. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
  "publishConfig": {
      "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.org"
  }
```

More details can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages)

Comment: I don't actually want to publish to npm. I just want to be able to "install" with the npm command from a git repo